# How to attach a LineObj y value to a specific Y axis?

Tags: c#, winforms, zedgraph

I am using [ZedGraph](https://github.com/discomurray/ZedGraph) and I am having a hard time drawing horizontal lines that crosses each Y axes on a `GraphPane` object.

Drawing a horizontal line on a `GraphPane` is trivial:

```
var l = new LineObj(0, y, 1, y);
l.IsClippedToChartRect = true;
l.Location.CoordinateFrame = CoordType.XChartFractionYScale;
pane.GraphObjList.Add(l);
```

However, things are getting more complicated when I have multiple CurveItems attached to many Y axes on the same GraphPane.

I need to draw a horizontal line for each CurveItem, using the scale of any other Y axes than Y or Y2.

```
foreach(var ci in pane.CurveItems)
{
    ...
    var l = new LineObj(0, y, 1, y);
    l.IsClippedToChartRect = true;
    l.Location.CoordinateFrame = ??? // CoordType.XChartFractionYScale is for the main Y axis !
    // How to specify a Y value for LineObj
    // and "attach" it to another Y axis than Y and Y2 ?
}
```

Meanwhile, I could use

```
var yaxis = ci.GetYAxis(foundPane);
var yy = getHTarget(1d - (y - yaxis.Scale.Min) / (yaxis.Scale.Max - yaxis.Scale.Min));
...
l.Location.CoordinateFrame = CoordType.ChartFraction
```

but it does not really "attach" the LineObj to the Y axis scale.

It looks like I or ZedGraph are missing some parts here.
Something like `l.Location.YAxisIndex` used with a `XChartFractionYScaleIndexed` is lacking.

Before trying to write my custom GraphObj, I would like to hear if someone has a solution for this.

Comment: Managed to do something old chap ? :)

Comment: I am trying to mimic the cursors of the [yahoo finance](http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=%5EIXIC+Interactive#%7B%22scale%22%3A%22linear%22%7D) charts. It runs just ok using the ChartFraction tip, but I cannot have my GraphObj stuck to a specific axe. Because my trending application handles more than one Y axes that can zoom and pan separately, I would need this. For now, I have to hide the GraphObj once the mouse pointer is outside the chart :)

Comment: Hi Larry, ready for a chat ?

Comment: Oh I am sorry I am in vacation until the 5st January... :-}
I dont have my code with me unfortunately. Thank you for your proposal very much indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to be using the Curve object.

I describe making a horizontal dashed line below.

In response to your comment about Yahoo Finance graphs, you can do the same for vertical line with a 2nd curve object, and move the lines by reassigning the point pairs for the curve objects.

~mike

```
//reference to the graph to draw on
GraphPane oPane = ZedGraph.MasterPane[0];

double fMinX = 0;
double fMaxX = 100;
double fYvalue = 42;

//values for the point pair list to define the horizontal line
var oPPL = new PointPairList();
oPPL.Add(fMinX, fYvalue);
oPPL.Add(fMaxX, fYvalue);

//draw the line as a curve object, then format....
var oPoints = oPane.AddCurve(string.Empty, oPPL, Color.Red, SymbolType.None);
oPoints.Line.IsVisible = true;
oPoints.Line.Style = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash;
oPoints.Line.Width = 3F;
oPoints.Symbol.IsVisible = false;

//and hang on to the curve object so you can move the line around as needed
            oPoints.Clear();
            oPoints.AddPoint(blah blah blah...
```